# Magento 301 redirects for certain pages

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I was advised from a SEO specialist to 301 redirect certain pages (e.g. .com/about-us , .com/contact-us) from my Magento installation to a version with ending / trailing slash.

What would be the best way to have this accomplished and just affect the desired pages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming then that this will be a redirect from one page to another, if I wanted to move and/or rename this page to a new URL, for example:

From: http://www.domain.com/old-url.html

To: http://www.domain.com/new-url.html

I would do the following in Magento to create the appropriate permanent redirect:

1. Navigate to Catalog > Url Rewrite Management
2. Click the “Add Urlrewrite” button
3. Select “Custom” from the “Create Urlrewrite” drop-down menu
4. The “Urlrewrite Information” form would be completed thusly:

ID Path: old-url.html
Request Path: old-url.html
Target Path: http://www.domain.com/new-url.html
Redirect: Permanent(301)

So, to recap:
ID Path and Request path are the same: the path off the root of the url to redirect FROM – everything after (not including) the domain name and trailing slash.
Target path is the URL to redirect TO.

or try this

http://www.isitebuild.com/301-redirect.htm

hope this will help you